# Line Graph Adding Value of Series 1 to Series 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm working on a line graph that contains two lines (each representing two different sets of data) with percentage values for each time period.  In the first time period, the value for Set A is 3% while the value for Set B in time period 1 is 7%.  The issue that I'm having is that instead of graphing 7% for Set B, it's graphing 10% (the 7% value is being added to the 3%).  Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a “Stacked line” chart (possibly “with Markers”), like this:

[image: before]

You need to change your chart type …

[image: the menu]

… to “Line” (possibly “with Markers”):

[image: the dialog box]

When I did it, with the data shown, I got this:

[image: after]